# Bootstrap Sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar, fluid-layout

Ok in short, I want to create a layout using bootstrap and sidebars then include in on my drupal website. All is working fine but now I want the content page to stretch the whole with if there is no sidebar content. Please help. A

Comment: I already have it working, it's just static empty sidebar is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you using?

it sounds like you just need to do some css, use the dev-tool in chrome to style your page.

Stanford has a great theme with nice tutorial. 
[Bootstrap tutorial for drupal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IlqcR30wuY)

Comment: It's a custom theme. I have looked at Staford....yes, it can handle what I need but I wanted to use my custom theme...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer. I'll just post it here. It might help somebody trying to design their own theme using Twitter Bootstrap and Drupal.

`<div class="<?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): print 'col-lg-8'; else: print 'col-lg-12'; endif; ?>">`